# Getting UI Automator to show a property "checked"

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I have a subclass of ImageView as follows:

```
public class CheckedImageView extends ImageView {
    private boolean checked;
...
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }
}
```

When I dump the UI Automation using eclipse I do not get the proper result for the "checked" property. Any idea how to fix so that UI Automator shows the correct value of checked?

Comment: did you try viewing UI properties with `uiautomatorviewer` ?

Comment: Navigate to your SDK via command line. Then enter `uiautomatorviewer`. Then in the top left, hit the button that looks like a android. Thats a screen shot. You can now see details of the views, and reference them in your test.

Comment: I have tried this and it does not show. It is essentially the same as what is run from Eclipse